# How to make GDATAXML compatible with ARC in XCODE 4.2?

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting, gdataxml

I tried to convert GDATAXML Lib to ARC automatically with the refractor -> Convert to ARC Objective-C in XCode 4.2.

The ARC converter gives the following error:

```
  result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) chars];
  if (cacheDict) {
    // save the string in the document's string cache
    CFDictionarySetValue(cacheDict, chars, result);
  }
```

> error: Impicit conversion of Ojective-C pointer to void.

Has anyone succeeded in converting the GDATAXML Libs to ARC Objective-C?

Answer (score 7):

please follow the instructions on how to make GDataXML work on your code: http://ibombsite.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-make-gdataxmlnode-work.html

Comment: I will save you a click - Select Build Phases tab.
Expand Compile Sources.
Select GDataXMLNode.m then press Enter.
On the small input box that pops-out, enter -fno-objc-arc.

Answer (score 3):

I found someone who has (apparently successfully) done the refactor for ARC.

see: http://www.michaelbabiy.com/arc-compliant-gdataxml-library/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bridged cast:
`CFDictionarySetValue(cacheDict, chars, (__bridge_retained_void*) result);`
Check out Apple's article ["Transitioning to ARC"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html), especially the [part about briding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1).